# Linux AIO / io_submit / io_getevents / on fifo (named pipes)

Tags: linux, io, fifo, async

I have to write a lot of data to a pipe. Can I use the Linux calls
`io_submit/io_getevents` for writing to Named Pipes or it is defined only for regular files.  I tried finding any document which explains the AIO over pipes but couldn't. Can someone help here.

Majorly I am concerned about the `aio_offset` field in `struct iocb`. What if a data packet with offset 8096 is scheduled for read/write before a data packet of offset as 4096.

Answer (score 1):

Linux AIO is not just limited to regular files - it *can* be used on block device special files.  I expect AIO writes cannot be used on pipes though, due to pipes not being capable of seeking.

`IOCB_CMD_PWRITE`

> pwrite() writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to the file descriptor fd at offset offset. The file offset is not changed.
>
> The file referenced by fd must be capable of seeking.

The point of AIO, is to be able to queue multiple direct IO writes (or reads) to a block device without having to use threads.

To improve the performance of bulk transfers over a pipe, I would suggest increasing the pipe buffer size from 4kB, to not more than 64kB... except that 64kB is already the default on modern Linux.

Comment: Linux AIO not working with pipes is mentioned in the [AIOUserGuide](https://github.com/littledan/linux-aio#performance-considerations) and the [Kernel Asynchronous I/O (AIO) Support for Linux](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html) page.